# How can I export the current map composer extent to a layer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, grids-graticules

In QGIS, I am trying to use the [Create Grid for Indexing plugin](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/createnamedgrid/) more efficiently. I would like to know if it is possible to export a map composer extent to a layer (a layer with one rectangle polygon) in order to use it as the layer extent in the Create Grid for Indexing plugin.

Answer (score 2):

I did something similar once but instead of creating a new layer for the map composer extent:

1. I set up the extent from the composer
2. Clicked the **View extent in map canvas** option:

   [image: View extent in map canvas]
3. From the plugin, I selected the extent of the canvas:

   [image: Create grid for indexing plugin]

This allowed me to bypass having to create another 'mask' layer.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that but my canvas doesn't match my map composer proportion so it fits in the dimension but not the other. or may be I am missing something.

Comment: @user274593 - Not sure but I guess it depends on how the maps are used. I made fairly simply maps so didn't have an issue with proportion but this may be an issue if you're working with really high-quality maps.

Comment: I'm not sure that it is a matter of quality. In my case the map in the composer is in _portrait_ whereas my canvas is in _landscape_; so it fits well in height but not in width. I can manage to manually adjust my canvas proportions with my window size to fit the best to my map proportions but it can not fit perfectly.

Comment: @user274593 - Have you tried setting your composer to _portrait_?

Comment: If I use approximative same proportions in the map composer and the canvas it fits _fairly_ well but I am looking for a grid which fits _perfectly_ in my map composer, that is why I was looking for an export of the map composer extent as a layer.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to get **zoom to extent** to work without gaps, as you've found. It gives "best fit" when the aspect ratios don't match.

(Tip : when messing around with extents, use **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>** to save extents on a saved layer, that way you can always get your extent back, even after closing QGIS)

**Snapping indexed grid to bounding box**

If you want to create a grid over the extent of a layer:-

Make sure the layer is selected in the Layers panel first, then click on **Selected Layer** in the plugin. It should then build the grid inside that rectangle.

If you uncheck the option **add labels outside extent** that will create a plain grid.. that might make things easier in composer.

You could then use composer to expand to fit the content (needs QGIS >2.12?)